# Can not send System.TimeSpan to my WebService

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, timespan

In my WebService I use TimeSpan to save record in my database, but when instantiate the object in the application that uses the WebService I receive the following message:

```
Cannot convert source type 'System.TimeSpan' to target type 'MyWebservice.TimeSpan'.
```

That's how the TimeSpan is called in my WebService:

```
public System.TimeSpan? WaitingTime {get; set;}
```

That's how the WebService reference is updated in my application:

```
private TimeSpan waitingTimeField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=12)]
public TimeSpan WaitingTime {
    get {
       return this.waitingTimeField;
    }
    set {
        this.waitingTimeField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("WaitingTime");
    }
}
```

If I change the references of the WebService, there is a conflict between the reference and the webservice making it impossible to use it.

I've tried to create an object of type MyWebService.TimeSpan and this made it possible to create the WaitingTime object, but can not send parameters for the object, so the MyWebService.TimeSpan is always 00:00:00

**EDIT:**

I tried to change the WebService reference to:

```
private System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan> waitingTimeField;
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=12)]
public System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan> WaitingTime
{
    get {
        return this.waitingTimeField;
    }
    set {
        this.waitingTimeField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("WaitingTime");
    }
}
```

So the problems in the application over, but when I send to the WebService a filled TimeSpan, the WebService "resets" it, so what was 00:03:02:1321465 becomes 00:00:00

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34281")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class TimeSpan : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to send a `long` instead of a `TimeSpan`, just to simplify things and also shrink the message a bit.

You can convert back and forth easily:

```
var numTicks = someTimeSpan.Ticks;
var newTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(numTicks);
```

As far as your problem, I believe it's because `TimeSpan` doesn't appear to be serializable. I just serialized one using `XmlSerializer`, and it was empty (`<TimeSpan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />`).

`TimeSpan` is immutable, so my guess is your serializer just doesn't know how to serialize and/or deserialize one.

Comment: It was not an ideal form because it caused the need for multiple conversions, but it was the only solution found.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you made TimeSpan class nullable ("?" sign). Make both TimeSpans(on service and client)  nullable or get rid of ? and see if error still exists with not nullable Timespans.

Comment: I tried this, but when I force the references to accept the Nullable System.TimeSpan the WebService does not recognize the object, and call the WS method the TimeSpan is 0:00:00 in the WS;

Comment: Do you actually use WCF for your  WebService ? If yes please post ServiceContract interface.